# Mosaicking images with Dask array

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I know that item assignment in Dask arrays is not possible but I wonder if there is a better way of doing the following.

The (simplified) problem is as follow: I have got 100 images (2048x2048) that need to be mosaicked together to make a large 20000x20000 mosaic. These images do overlap so as a first step I compute the offsets between pairs and then their absolute position in the large mosaic. Now it comes the problem of creating the mosaic.

Currently what I am doing is sending all the small images (as dask arrays) to a delayed function that uses normal numpy slicing to build the mosaic. Issues with this approach is that is not done in parallel, it requires quite a bit of memory per mosaic since the arrays are stored in just one process/thread and there is a communication overhead because all images in dask arrays need to be transferred to a single thread. Anyway this is the pseudocode:

```
@delayed
def mosaic(imgs, abs_pos, output_shape):
    big_image = np.zeros(output_shape)
    weight_image = np.zeros(output_shape)
    for i in range(len(imgs)):
        im= imgs[i]
        y_pos, x_pos = abs_pos[i]
        y_size, x_size = im.shape
        big_image[y_pos + y_size, x_pos + x_size] += im
        weight_image[y_pos + y_size, x_pos + x_size] += 1
    return big_image, weight_image
```

here imgs is a list of dask arrays, abs_pos is a lost containing the absolute position of one of the corners of each image in the mosaic and output_shape is 20000x20000.

In reality several of these mosaics need to be computed, so the task stream plot looks like the following:

[dask stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVvMC.png)

where it is building here three mosaics, red is transfer of data to the thread and green the mosaic function.

I am wondering if there is a better solution to make this more parallel.

Comment: https://blog.dask.org/2021/12/01/mosaic-fusion is about this